# Writing a function for mapping id in df1 with all the possible matching id columns in df2 in R

Tags: r

```
table_A: employee_id, internal_id, ...

table_B: unknown_id, department
```

What would be the better way  to write a function that matching unknown_id in table_B with each of the id columns in table_A sequentially?

Pseudocode/idea:

```
step1 <- table_A %>% 
     left_join (table_B, by=(employee_id = unknown_id)

step2 <- step1 %>% 
     filter(is.na(department)) ***# get all the non-matching rows***

step3 <- step2 %>%
     left_join (table_B, by= (internal_id = unknown_id))

step4 <- step3 %>%
     filter(is.na(department)  ***# get all the non-matching rows again, then try other id columns if it is available***
```

Comment: What do you mean by "matching random_id" exactly? Do you mean any value in `table_A` that you choose? For instance, `employee_id`?

Comment: But then in step3 you are using `internal_id`. So I don't understand what you are trying to do. More info on your 2 initial objects and on what you want to do would be helpful

Comment: It'd help if you provide some sample data.